# Edit after uploading the image in jquery codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I want to edit the image rotation after upload.here is my jquery code . i rotate the image successfully but while i want to save its doing nothing .

```
var value = 0
$("#change_image_rotate").rotate({ 
   bind: 
     { 
        click: function(){
            value +=90;
            $(this).rotate({ animateTo:value})
            $('#rotate_val').val(value);
        }
     } 

});
function editImage(img_src){
$('#change_image_rotate').attr("src","<?php echo base_url();?>bric_gallery/"+img_src);
$('#img_val_rotate').val(img_src);
}
```

[This is the image of my portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8K5T.png)

This is my html section where i get the rotation value and image name.

```
 <form action="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/gallery/rotate_image" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="img_val_rotate" name="img_val_rotate"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="rotate_val" name="rotate_val"/>
```

and this is my codeigniter code .

```
$config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
                $config['source_image'] = './bric_gallery/'.$this->input->post('img_val_rotate'); //get original image
                $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
                $config['rotation_angle'] = $this->input->post('rotate_val');//counter-clockwise angle of rotation
                $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
                if ($this->image_lib->rotate()) {
                    echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
                }
```

please help me out .

Answer (score 0):

i think their must be in problem with your rotation_angle value echo $this->input->post('rotate_val'); and prin_r your $config

and most important thing is you are using wrong condition to echo errors just add ! operator in your if like this 
`if(! $this->image_lib->resize() )`

Comment: print_r returns Array ( [image_library] => gd2 [source_image] => ./bric_gallery/IMG_2030.JPG [maintain_ratio] => 1 [rotation_angle] => 90 )

Comment: i change as you told . but noting happen.

Comment: have you tried to change the if condition with if(! $this->image_lib->resize() )    and check your directory and file it is affected or not

Comment: ok i get try to remove . dot from source image path '/bric_gallery/'